# WSO2 ESB: Can we use Call Mediator for Rest Service to post (POST HTTP Method) the xml request?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When I create proxy with send mediator with Rest service Post HTTP Method in HTTP endpoint url. Selected the endpoint as HTTP endpoint on proxy and post the request xml without soap envelop, this perfectly works and get the response in the response window.

But when I use the call mediator with the same HTTP end point url  configuration, this does not works. I would like to know can we use call mediator for Post HTTP method? When I use Call mediator for the GET HTTP method which require only query parameters and does not require any request xml this works absolutely fine.

Here is the further information:

However issue is resloved by using the address endpoint in callmediator. When I Invoke the proxy from external Restt client ot Soap UI, it does works. If I use the Try this Service option in wso2 ESB will fail with the results 1. When Soap12 endpoint is selected  and 2 when HTTP end point is selected as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="postIDMPCall"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="ContentType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <organizationList xmlns="">
                <xml content>
               </organizationList>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
        <header name="_user" scope="transport" value="username"/>
         <header name="_password" scope="transport" value="Password"/>
<call blocking="true">
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://<ip-address>:<port>/<resource-path>/UpdateOrganization"
                        format="rest"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
        </inSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

1. Output: When soap12 endpoint is selected
   Though posted the correct xml service does not recorgonize the correct xml format for soap12 endpoint.

   FAILURE
        Record is not processed successfully. Please Provide valid Request XML

   2. When Http end point is selected

   [2016-04-21 12:07:50,179]  INFO - HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://://UpdateOrganization/mediate]

   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
           at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)

Comment: Could you please elaborate. What is the error? What does your proxy look like?

Comment: Can you please share you proxy code?

Answer (score 0):

I think we can't use call mediator for this purpose because call mediator is context unaware mediator.

Answer (score 0):

Your call should already perform a post out the box.
Did you try to set `format="pox"` if you expect simple xml as a response